# Webdriverio - Element Not Visible

Tags: webdriver-io

it's my first time posting here in Stackoverflow.

Currently I'm working with WebdriverIO using the Mocha Framework and Selenium-Standalone. I'm in my work placement currently and I've been tasked to do some automation testing.

My problem is a particular element - the **fa-trash**:

```
  <label class="gf-form-label">
        <a ng-click="ctrl.toggleHideQuery()" role="menuitem">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
        </a>
    </label>
    <label class="gf-form-label">
        <a class="pointer" tabindex="1" ng-click="ctrl.removeQuery(ctrl.target)">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </a>
    </label>
```

Every time I try clicking on it, it outputs a message that the element does not exist.

Code Snippet:

```
it('should Delete', function(){
    browser.pause(500);
    browser.click('.fa-trash');
    browser.pause(2000);
});
```

I'm able to click the **fa-eye** fine without error, which hides the current element in the browser but if I try clicking the **fa-trash**, it will give me a message that it does not exist.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Could it be that the element is not there for a brief moment when you are trying to click on it? You could use `.waitForVisible('.fa-trash', 5000)` before attempting the click.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer @tehbeardedone. I've tried using `browser.waitForVisible('.fa-trash', 5000)`(I might be doing it wrong?) before I attempted clicking and it still gave me the same error. However, I did find a workaround it by, instead of using the `fa-trash` class name, I just used and clicked the label wrapped around it.